# IndexedDB mixed transaction mode

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

My service is reponsible for creating and storing into IndexedDB a complex object involving several object stores. Currently I'm opening the transaction in `readwrite` mode:

```
db.transaction(['tournament', 'schedule', 'player'], 'readwrite')
```

However, the `schedule` object store is never updated in this transaction, only queried, and I'd rather let the engine know this fact. So, the question is: **is there a way to request several storages with different modes, independently?**

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not supported in the API.